# Finding duplicates between two columns same table

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe

I want to find duplicate values between two columns without a id.
Example:

table **employees**

```
-----------------------------------
employee_one    | employee_two    |    
-----------------------------------
JOHN SMITH      | JACK STEVENS    |
MASON LEWIS     | JOHN WALKER     |
ANDREA YOUNG    | MARTINA ROBINSON|
JACK STEVENS    | JOHN SMITH      |
JOHN WALKER     | MASON LEWIS     |
MARTINA ROBINSON| ANDREA YOUNG    |
```

and the results I want is:

```
-----------------------------------
employee_one    | employee_two    |    
-----------------------------------
JOHN SMITH      | JACK STEVENS    |
MASON LEWIS     | JOHN WALKER     |
ANDREA YOUNG    | MARTINA ROBINSON|
```

or

```
-----------------------------------
employee_one    | employee_two    |    
-----------------------------------
JACK STEVENS    | JOHN SMITH      |
JOHN WALKER     | MASON LEWIS     |
MARTINA ROBINSON| ANDREA YOUNG    |
```

My problem is that my query always find all the results and I get the same table. I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
    FROM employees 
    AS t1 LEFT JOIN employees AS t2 ON (t1.employee_one = t2.employee_two AND t1.employee_two = t2.employee_one) 
OR (t1.employee_one = t2.employee_one AND t1.employee_two = t2.employee_two)
```

But I get the same results

Comment: Duplicate of value from column one in column two, is also a duplicate of value from column two in column one. What is the criterion that value should land one one column and not the other?

Comment: There isnt a a criterion. I just have to find the duplicate values that have two same employees inverted. They have to be both two in the same row. If its only one I'll pass it.

Comment: well maybe thats the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Every pair of names will show up twice, so use a where clause to limit the output to just those where employee_one < employee_two:

```sql
select t1.*
from employees t1
where employee_one < employee_two
  and exists (
    select *
    from employees t2
    where t2.employee_two = t1.employee_one
      and t2.employee_one = t1.employee_two)
```

Caveat: this assumes that there are no rows where employee_one = employee_two.

Comment: There are some but they should not exist. Thanks, it seems to work pretty well.